# What is the difference between parent *:hover {} and parent:hover * {}?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm wondering what is the difference between CSS selectors.
If I'm changing this:

```
.parent *:hover {}
```

to this:

```
.parent:hover * {}
```

in the subsequent code:

```css
#child {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.parent {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.parent:hover * { 
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>HTML Sample</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="parent">
      <div id="child"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Nothing changes** and *hover* effect remains same. Am I missing smth here?

Comment: For this particular example, I see no difference. However, there is one, if `.parent` would have multiple children or if `#child` would not cover the whole of `.parent`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- `.parent *:hover {}` means: **target all descendants of any element with `class="parent"`, while in a hover-state"** (that is, while the descendant is hovered)
- `.parent:hover * {}` means **target all descendants of any element with `class="parent"`, while the element with `class="parent"` is in a hover-state** (note that if a descendant element is hovered, so is the `.parent`, even if they don't form a single cohesive visual unit (e.g. `position: absolute` is being used).

If your `<div class="parent">` has multiple children then the first rule (`.parent *:hover {}`) will only affect a single descendant *while* that specific descendant is hovered - so if the user mouse-overs another element then the style-rule would change.

The second rule is such that provided that `.parent` is mouse-hovered, then all descendants will have their styles changed. This is not a good style rule because the descendant selector will select *everything* under `.parent` (e.g. every single `<span>`, `<a>`, `<p>`, etc). You probably should use a more specific selector.

Answer (score 1):

Easy. Please hover to the parrent and then to the child.

```css
#child {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.parent {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 100px;
}

.parent:hover * { 
  background-color: red;
}

.parent *:hover { 
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>HTML Sample</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="parent">
      <div id="child"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

For `.parent:hover * {}`, the selector applies to children as soon as you hover over any part of the parent. You can see this in **first box** by hovering the green part (i.e. padding of the parent), and the color of child will change.

For `.parent *:hover {}`, the selector is only triggered when a child is hovered. So in the snippet below, for **second box**, when you hover over the green part (i.e. padding of the parent), the color of child doesn't change. But if you hover over the white part, which is the box of the child, the color will change.

```css
#child {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.parent,
.parent2{
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 50px;
}

.parent *, .parent2 *
{
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.parent:hover * { 
  background-color: red;
}

.parent2 *:hover { 
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>HTML Sample</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="parent">
      <div id="child">1</div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="parent2">
      <div id="child">2</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```